# IP68 LED strip installation underwater (suitable methods and materials)

Tags: led, waterproofing, adhesive

I need to install IP68-rated RGB LED strips in a pool. The LED strips will be submerged in water. What would be the right method to do so? I can think of a few options:

1. Use the 3M tape on the reverse side of LED strip - This is likely to fail fast because water and salts/chemicals will degrade the 3M tape quickly. What's your opinion on this?
2. Use plastic clips and screws to hold the strip - This is likely to give good long term stability. However I am not sure if making so many small holes in the pool area will be a good idea. Another idea is to fix 10 mm thick and 40 mm wide PVC strip and then screw the clips on this PVC strip. PVC strip can also be stuck to the surface using some epoxy resin or some other waterproof glue and then the clips can be screwed on the PVC strip.
3. Use some sort of waterproof glue to stick the LED strip directly to the pool surface. I am not sure what glue to use? Is silicone glue right for this use case?

Since the use case is outdoors, the strip is likely to require replacement after 2-3 years. I want a method that allows for this. Any suggestions/recommendations will be very helpful.

Comment: I would consider mounting clear plastic tubing (PVC or other material) under water and putting the LEDs inside of the tubes.  You could use regular LEDs and if you avoid sharp bends you might be able to thread replacement LEDs, if needed, through the tubes.

Comment: i would use a non-chincy amount of low-temp hot glue.

Comment: @steve - the led strips are IP68 rated by default. The strip is fully encapsulated into transparent silicon. I just need a way to attach it securely to the wall surface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd be thinking about using aquarium silicone. It is stronger and more flexible than regular silicone but can easily be removed when the lights fail. I used this to build an aquarium and it's holding power is great. The surfaces have to be dry to apply and dry for the curing time.

Comment: Will it hold up submerged in pool water? and does it come off clean when removed (similar to pulling an elastic band)?

Comment: It should hold up submerged since it does in salt water aquariums. It might pull off in a strip of need to skim a one sided razor blade under it.

Comment: That'd be perfect. Thanks Jack.